# TFS - Find details of known changeset ID

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs, changeset

I know the ID of a changeset that im interested in seeing the details of. Is there anywhere i can enter the ID of a changeset in order to see what changes were included in the commit without having to know what branch the change was made in?

Im using VS2010 / TFS2010.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Set the focus on SourceControlExplorer in VS and press CTRL+G

Answer (score 7):

In the Source Control Explorer in VS2010, click the "Find Changeset" icon on the toolbar.

Answer (score 1):

From the command line you can use 'tf.exe changeset ID'.

Be aware that your current directory needs to be a mapped workspace on the server you're trying to look up the changeset on. Otherwise you need to specify /s:servername (e.g. /s:http://tfsserver:8080/tfs

Answer (score 1):

Extension to Rassi's answer to get everything on command prompt

From the command line you can use `tf.exe changeset <<changeset ID>> /noprompt`

[Microsoft link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w51xa47k%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)